# Unable to get value of the property 'offsetWidth' : object is null or undefined error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a page that is basically being set up as a table with three rows. The the top row is the header, the middle row is the main part of the page, and the bottom row is the navigation. Each button in the navigation row fires off a javascript function which using the innerHTML value of the middle row and places the necessary html to show the contents of the page.
On the main page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

In the head section I have:

```
var myOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), zoom: 8, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
```

In the body section so that it runs right away and then in the function that is called by the MAP Button I have:

```
var mapString;
var w = document.getElementById("mainwindow");
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
mapString = '<table width="1024" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
mapString += '<td> <div id="map_canvas" width="1024" height="350"></div></td>';
mapString += '</tr></table>';
w.innerHTML = mapString;
```

Now when I press the Map button I get the error:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'offsetWidth': object is null or undefined
main.js Line 29
Code 0 char:1385
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-2/3/2/main.js
```

Not sure what this error is trying to tell me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

do the

```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

last because `map_canvas` div doesn't exist when google maps attempts to load the map into that div.

should read like this

```
var mapString;
var w = document.getElementById("mainwindow");
mapString = '<table width="1024" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
mapString += '<td> <div id="map_canvas" width="1024" height="350"></div></td>';
mapString += '</tr></table>';
w.innerHTML = mapString;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had the same problem with Google Maps in a GWT/SmartGWT application.